# Div ignoring set width constraints, CSS

Tags: css, layout

all. I have this problem where I have explicitly set out how wide a certain div dhould be, yet it ignores it.
I have a wrapper, and in it I want side by side a sidebar and a content bar. The content bar seem to be pushing away the sidebar and filling up all the space.

Code in Question:

```
#wrapper{
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -2em;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
}

#content{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 175px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

And the HTML is simply
    
    
    
    Blah Blah Blah
    
    
    
In a nutshell

I put Lorem Ipsum where content is, and I put some Lorem Ipsum in the sidebar. Element Inspector in chrome shows content to be 700 pixels wide, even though i declared it to be 400px. I dont care about ie6 compatibility really.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnXEp.jpg Is how it should look.

Someone said somehting about fiddles. Am I doing this right http://jsfiddle.net/R3Wyw/1/
The big Lorem Ipsum chunk be skinnier, only 400 pixels of text, while the sidebar should move up and slot in beside it.

Comment: Please post also the HTML code or a fiddle

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3Wyw/

Comment: `#content` for me doesn't show up as 700px wide. It's **475px** wide, because of the padding.

Comment: Added fiddle a quick explanation i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You've basic HTML and CSS syntax problems in your code:

- HTML ending tags should be written `</div>` and never ever `</div id="content">`.

Good:

```
    <div id="content" class="something" role="main">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
```

Bad:

```
    <div id="content" class="something" role="main">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div id="content" class="something" role="main">
```

- CSS comments must be written `/* a CSS comment */`, not `<-- HTML comment -->`

You should try to validate your code in http://validator.w3.org (HTML) and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ (CS) before posting (use the Web Developer Toolbar extension on Firefox to do it fast).
Error messages are sometimes a bit cryptic but they're always the same ;) Google for them to get explanations or ask here on SO.

For width problems, I add different background-color to elements and parents, to better see which one isn't as expected (and which one has only floating children and thus no real content in the flow anymore thus no height thus no visible background color...). Like lightblue, lightgreen, pink, lightyellow, etc This and MeasureIt! extension on Fx.